# Can a dual citizen with expired US passport leave the country with the foreign passport and request an emergency replacement to come back home?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, consulates

We have a travel to Europe in 2 weeks and my friend just realized her US passport was expired since 2019. She's also a Brazilian citizen with a valid Brazilian passport. In a naive act of despair, she went to passportsandvisas.com, paid for expedited processing and mailed them her expired passport for renewal. I doubt she'll get a new passport back within 2 weeks (or ever), so here's my thinking:

- She can leave US to Europe with the Brazilian passport
- If she doesn't get a new passport by then, she could go to a consulate in Europe and request an emergency passport to fly back home
- Worst case, since she's working remotely these days, she can fly to Rio after the trip (where she has family and won't have to pay for hotel or AirBnB) and request an emergency passport at the consulate (even if it takes a few weeks, it wouldn't be a big deal)

In theory, it seems it might work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you bought the tickets already?  If so, on what airline?

Comment: Also see https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast/courier-and-expeditor-companies.html for more information about third-party companies.

Comment: She'll fly Delta (we hope). Yes, these third-party companies are shady, to say the least.

Comment: You can also fly to Mexico and cross overland with an expired passport, no emergency passport needed.

Comment: I can see your friend having a really uncomfortable time when the consulate asks her why she didn't get her passport renewed before travelling, and then travelling anyway.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "can". It's unlawful, but there are no penalties or consequences for it. Is that "can" to you?

Comment: Unlike some countries, the USA doesn't check your USA passport when you leave the country, expired or otherwise. You have to show _some_ passport to airline personnel appropriate to getting on the airplane. So, for example, she could fly to any country that does not require advance visas for Brazilian nationals (and does not have some covid restriction that prevents entry). Once overseas she could go the emergency route or travel on the Brazilian passport until returning to the USA. That may be a little sticky. Does she have her old passport number? A photo?